# Scroll up/down stops working in Chrome Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, mouse, hardware, mouse-scroll

So I open a page, read some stuff and then suddenly scrolling with mouse wheel stops working, it's definitely a mouse problem because scrolling with keys up and down is working. After I reload the page scroll starts working again. Any thoughts?! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue but I was able to fix this by disabling smooth scrolling via chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling

Although I didn't get the same experience of scrolling thereafter on Chrome but it stopped this from happening.

Comment: Anyone see a bug # on chromium tickets?

Comment: Appears to have been fixed on chrome 75 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=945693&q=scrolling%20linux&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ubuntu 18.04, Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)
I was able to fix this by disabling smooth scrolling via chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling